# Apple Mach-O Linker Error. Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I got stuck at this point for days. I'm trying to build my old project on iOS using Unity 5.3.1f1 (old Unity version was 3.5.7f6), Xcode 6.1 + iOS SDK 8.1. Got the following error. I fixed all compiling errors but cannot get through these issues. Thanks in advance!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
 "_ga_dispatch", referenced from:
    _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_dispatch_m_1985977664_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
    _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_dispatch_m_1985977664_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
   (maybe you meant: _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_dispatch_m_1985977664_0)
"_ga_sendEvent", referenced from:
    _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_sendEvent_m_796108308_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
    _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_sendEvent_m_796108308_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
   (maybe you meant: _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_sendEvent_m_796108308_0)
"_ga_init", referenced from:
    _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_init_m_945665034_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
    _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_Init_m1934083825_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
    _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_init_m_945665034_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
    _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_Init_m1934083825_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
   (maybe you meant: _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_init_m_945665034_0)
"_ga_stopTracker", referenced from:
   _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_stopTracker_m_197343630_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
   _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_Destroy_m_692452965_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
   _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_stopTracker_m_197343630_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
   _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_Destroy_m_692452965_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
   (maybe you meant: _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_stopTracker_m_197343630_0)
"_ga_startTracker", referenced from:
  _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_startTracker_m_1249043631_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
  _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_startTracker_m_1249043631_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
   (maybe you meant: _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_startTracker_m_1249043631_0)
 "_ga_sendView", referenced from:
    _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_sendView_m_221331953_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
    _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_sendView_m_221331953_0 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.o
   (maybe you meant: _GoogleAnalyticsBinding_ga_sendView_m_221331953_0)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: So you are missing a library or two?

Comment: I already added them, but this error still appeared. I don't understand what happened. What should I do ? 
[Here is the screenshot. Was I doing right?](https://www.flickr.com/photos/139693837@N02/25235043711/in/shares-R252o8/)

Comment: Please check if you are using correct verison of framework, which support all latest architectures. Moreover, check architecture set in your build settings as well

Comment: I tried to add the Google Analytics library (both the old libGoogleAnalytics.a & the GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS ver 3.13), but these errors still occur.

I also run:

    lipo -info libGoogleAnalytics.a (the old one when I used in Unity 3.5.7f6), it returned: 
    Architectures in the fat file: /ROOT/libGoogleAnalytics.a are: armv7 armv7s i386 
    
    lipo -info libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a (GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS ver 3.13), it returned:
    Architectures in the fat file: /ROOT/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many searches & tries, this one work for my situation:

- Re-build Xcode project from Unity and switch back to ***Mono2x*** (instead of IL2CPP).
- Add ***StoreKit.framework***, ***CoreData.framework***, ***SystemConfiguration.framework***
- Add the ***-ObjC*** in Other Linker Flags

( The [GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.13](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download) work just fine. And I wasn't really understood, but i had to disable Bitcode.)

Thanks ! Hope this help other folks !

Comment: finally...lifesaver!